# Pylint meanings of the C E W R Literals

Tags: python, pylint

I've searched already for a while, but didn't come with a detailed answer, when using pylint you get a message as following:

```
C:201, 0: Line too long (113/100) (line-too-long)
E:  3, 0: No name QImage in module QtCore
R: 27, 4: Too many statements (62/50) (too-many-statements)
```

Besides the fact that I didn't find a good ressource for all the messages (as search results just talk about linters but not the published docs), i couldn't completely guess what the literals `C`, `E`, `R`, `W` exactly mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly from the man pages:

```
OUTPUT
       Using the default text output, the message format is :

                MESSAGE_TYPE: LINE_NUM:[OBJECT:] MESSAGE

       There are 5 kind of message types :
           * (C) convention, for programming standard violation
           * (R) refactor, for bad code smell
           * (W) warning, for python specific problems
           * (E) error, for probable bugs in the code
           * (F) fatal, if an error occurred which prevented pylint from doing
       further processing.
```

Comment: Well THanks for the answer, I usually don't use the man command, should probably do it, is there an online ressource as well.